# Rails: how to generate view/action to existing controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I want to add a custome view to my existing controller
I need to create the `custom_page.erb`, add the `def custom_page` in `controller`, and add routes `get ...`. This is very repetative.

Is there any `generate command`, that can do this at once? Maybe something like `Rails generate CustomActionToMyController action_name`?

Answer (score 2):

Nope there is no direct way to do this.
Check this out [Create a new action for existing controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922819/create-a-new-action-for-existing-controller)