# New action created in a controller is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, routes

I am creating a Rails 4.2.6 /MongoDb app. I created a new action manually called 'calluser', made the change in routes to including it:

```
  resources :companies do
    member do
      get 'calluser'
    end
  end
```

I can see it when I execute the 'rake routes' command:

```
call_user_company GET  /companies/:id/call_user(.:format)   companies#call_user
```

However, When  I redirect from the controller:

> ```
>   if @company.save
>     format.html { redirect_to calluser_company(@company), notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
>     format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @company }
>   else
>     format.html { render action: 'new' }
>     format.json { render json: @company.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
>   end
> ```

I receive the following error:

```
undefined method `calluser_company' for #<CompaniesController:0x007fdd893f3270>
```

Any Idea why this is happening ? I will appreciate any help.

I read a previous similar problems but they didn't work for me:

[Create a new action for existing controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922819/create-a-new-action-for-existing-controller)

[Route a form to new controller action in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16283706/route-a-form-to-new-controller-action-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: the actual route is the one showing in the rake routes : `call_user_company` as you have written it "calluser_company" . Not sure why the underscore actually..

Comment: Sorry,  I pasted the wrong route:    calluser_company GET                       /companies/:id/calluser(.:format)                                         companies#calluser

Comment: then I am struggling to see where the problem come from. have you tried restarting the server ? By the way in the JSON you redirect to a different action (show)

Comment: The action is 'calluser' . That is the name everywhere. Sorry for pasting it wrong at the beginning. Yes, I have restarted the server every time a make a change in the controller.  The execution stops right at the format.html { redirect.... I changed from 'show' to 'calluser' but, it never reaches that point.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes describes:

`call_user_company GET  /companies/:id/call_user(.:format)   companies#call_user`

so you can use `call_user_company_url(@company)` or `call_user_company_path(@company)` instead of `calluser_company(@company)`

Comment: I need to add "_path" to be a restful application. calluser_company_path